# How do I count the number of times a number appears in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to count the number of times a number appears in a one dimensional array with a length of 5. I need to do this for 9 different numbers. The catch is that I am not allowed to sort the array OR create a new array and sort that one OR compare numbers in the pattern 1&2, 1&3, 1&4, 1&5, 2&3 etc... I am not allowed to use any outside functions and I can only use loops and conditional statements. Thank you!

For example the following Function will not work because it uses the above algorithm:

```
bool containsFourOfaKind(const int hand[])
{
    int doesMatch = 0;
    int x = 0;
    for (; x < 9; x++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (hand[i] == x)
                doesMatch++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of numbers can appear in the input array? What is it's size?

Comment: Use a `const std::vector<int>& hand` to represent a dynamically sized array.

Comment: only the numbers 2-9 can appear in the array

Comment: Can you solve the problem of "How many times the number 2 appears in an array?"

Comment: I am not sure how to solve that problem without using the code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make another array of integers to maintain a count.
2. Initialize all of the elements of the counting array to 0.
3. For each number in the input array,

   1. Use the number in the input array as the index of the counting array.
   2. Increment this element.

The counting array now contains the frequency of all of the values in the input array.

Comment: Doesn't this count as sorting another array though? I don't think that would be allowed in the assignment.

Comment: This is creating a new array, but it is not sorting. All that happens in the second array is counting.